# Aurelia layoutView is not working

Tags: routes, aurelia

I'm trying to create new route but with different view using `layoutView` attribute in the route config options but I get the below error :

**Error: Unable to find module with ID: reportBuilder/reportBuilderCreateDataset.html**

Here is my code :

```
{
    route: this.BASE_URL + 'reportBuilder',
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('reportBuilder/reportBuilder'),
    name: 'reportBuilder',
    title: 'Report Builder',
    settings: {
        roles: [],
        icoClass: 'fa fa-file-text-o'
    },
    nav: true
},
{
    route: this.BASE_URL + 'reportBuilder/query',
    moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('reportBuilder/reportBuilderCreateDataset'),
    name: 'reportBuilderCreateDataset',
    title: 'Report Builder from create dataset',
    layoutView: 'reportBuilder/reportBuilder.html'
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add `PLATFORM.modulename` with the layoutView like this: `layoutView: PLATFORM.modulename('reportBuilder/reportBuilder.html')` ?

Comment: Yes, I did with no luck

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stuck like me, I did it by creating the needed html view and used compose tag inside it to load the shared view and I can change it once from one file.